# Ethereum - Cannot allocate big buffer for DAG

Tags: cmd, ethereum

I am trying to do some mining but I keep on getting the following error (in cmd) when I run `start.bat`:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║     Claymore's Dual ETH + DCR/SC/LBC/PASC GPU Miner v10.0      ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

ETH: 5 pools are specified
Main Ethereum pool is eth-asia1.nanopool.org:9999
At least 16 GB of Virtual Memory is required for multi-GPU systems
Make sure you defined GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
Be careful with overclocking, use default clocks for first tests
Press "s" for current statistics, "0".."9" to turn on/off cards, "r" to reload pools, "e" or "d" to select current pool
OpenCL initializing...

AMD Cards available: 1
GPU #0: Hainan, 2048 MB available, 5 compute units
POOL/SOLO version
GPU #0: set -etha as 1 (ETH algo for slow cards)
No NVIDIA CUDA GPUs detected.
Total cards: 1
ETH: Stratum - connecting to 'eth-asia1.nanopool.org' <139.99.102.73> port 9999
ETHEREUM-ONLY MINING MODE ENABLED (-mode 1)
ETH: eth-proxy stratum mode
Watchdog enabled
Remote management (READ-ONLY MODE) is enabled on port 3333

ETH: Stratum - Connected (eth-asia1.nanopool.org:9999)
ETH: Authorized
Setting DAG epoch #159...
Setting DAG epoch #159 for GPU0
Create GPU buffer for GPU0
GPU0 - not enough GPU memory to place DAG, you cannot mine this coin with this GPU
GPU0 - OpenCL error -61 - cannot allocate big buffer for DAG. Check readme.txt for possible solutions.
Setting DAG epoch #159 for GPU0
GPU 0 failed
GPU0, OpenCL error -38 - cannot write buffer for DAG
```

Here is the content inside my notepad:

```
GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR 0
GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE 100
GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1
GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
EthDcrMiner64.exe -epool eth-asia1.nanopool.org:9999 -ewal <my address link> -epsw x -mode 1 -ftime 10
```

I have read the [readme.txt](https://ufile.io/pv49b) and changed the content in the notepad accordingly. But I get still this error.

Here is my system information:

```
                  Name: AMD Radeon (TM) R5 M335
          Manufacturer: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
             Chip Type: AMD Radeon Graphics Processor (0x6660)
              DAC Type: Interal DAC(400MHz)
           Device Type: Render-Only Display Device
  Approx. Total Memory: 6081 MB
 Display Memory (VRAM): 2039 MB
         Shared Memory: 4041 MB
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This belongs on Ethereum.SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Your hardware does not have enough ram to run this software.

Program requires 3GB video RAM, your graphics card has 2GB video RAM.

Graphics card memory cannot be upgraded by the user. You require a different graphics card.

> 10. If miner cannot generate DAG file, check environment variables (see Readme), **check if your GPU has 3GB memory at least**, and check if you have enough virtual memory (pagefile). If all this does not help, try to install more physical RAM.